# Getting Error: "sheet.indexOf is not a function" when creating dropdown in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I want to create a dropdown in the google sheets sidebar that will include the name all sheets that do NOT contain 'Lookup' in their name.

I'm trying to use scriptlets to filter the sheet names and this is what I got in the Page.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <!-- Select an exisiting data table -->
    Select sheet to classify: <br>
    <select id="dataSheetDropdown">
    <? var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets() ?>
    <? for(var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++) { ?>          
          <? sheet = sheets[i] ?>
          <? if(sheet.indexOf("Lookup")>-1){?>
          <option> <?= sheet.getName()?> </option>
          <? } ?>
    <? } ?>
    </select>
    <button onclick="selectLookup()">Select</button>
   
    
    
    <script> 
      function selectLookup(){
       var name=document.getElementsById("sheetDropdown")[0].value;
       google.script.run.goToSheet(name);
      };
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try and run this script, I get this error:

```
TypeError: sheet.indexOf is not a function
```

Any idea how I can get my script to run correctly? Your help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the sheet with the sheet name which don't include `Lookup` and show them to the dropdown list.

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason of your issue is that `sheet` is the sheet object. By this, such error occurs at `indexOf`.
- When you want to retrieve the sheet with the sheet name which don't include `Lookup`, please use `if(sheet.getSheetName().indexOf("Lookup") == -1){`.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
<? sheet = sheets[i] ?>
<? if(sheet.indexOf("Lookup")>-1){?>
<option> <?= sheet.getName()?> </option>
<? } ?>
```

To:

```
<? sheet = sheets[i] ?>
<? if(sheet.getSheetName().indexOf("Lookup") == -1){?>
<option> <?= sheet.getSheetName() ?> </option>
<? } ?>
```

#### References:

- [getSheetName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetName())
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)